# VPN through VPN question

Tags: vpn

I was wondering about data consumption and VPN through VPN. If I have a router connected to a vpn server within the same country as I am, then create another VPN tunnel through a software on my comptuter that is connected to a VPN in another country, which of the following is happening:

1. The second VPN tunnel exits to the foreign country from the router VPN server
2. The Second VPN tunnel ignores the first VPN server and goes directly from my computer to the specified country

If anyone could answer this, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Are you able to use "Traceroute" command to get some intermediate hops? Try using protocol as TCP in options, it help sometimes.

Comment: This is really not a duplicate question. The scenario is clearly different here and has a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the router is set up correctly ALL traffic would go through the first VPN on the router and then it would use your software and create a 2nd VPN connection.
no vpn connection should be ignored.

obviously though it depends on the network set up.

Comment: Does this mean the two connections are chained after each other or a tunnel inside a tunnel?

Comment: @st2erw2od There's no way to "chain" two VPN connections. The server terminating the first one does not know the info required to connect to the second one. The second VPN will just tunnel through the first one like any other traffic, provided the router is setup correctly.

Comment: @billc.cn ok that makes sense, but both tunnels end at the same point, so which one gets to see the unencrypted traffic? (the VPN set on the router or the one set in the client?) Why would you set something like this up anyway?

Comment: Only the VPN started by the client will transmit the data from the client. The VPN started by the router will only see a VPN connection coming out of it. The OP probably have a "secure router" of some sort for privacy and has another VPN for connecting to another country for some specific purpose.

Comment: @st2erw2od imagine this... its more of encapsulation... its hard to explain but imagine each VPN as its own entity... you cannot get to VPN2 without first end pointing the VPN1 (router) ... so essentially you have two out points....make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

The following scenario will try to explain:

- VPN1 - Portugal(router) - France
- VPN2 - Portugal(laptop) - Japan

Your connection will go from Portugal to France (using VPN1) and then to Japan (EXIT NODE - VPN2).